# Can't load Google Cloud Endpoints on Internet Explorer 10 and below

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, internet-explorer-10, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm working on a web site that is using the Google JavaScript Client
Library to load some APIs that are exposed via Google Cloud Endpoints.
Everything's working great in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but on Internet
Explorer 10 and below I get this error:

```
Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference
File: proxy.html, Line: 7, Column: 51
```

I've found similar questions but none of them have exact solution that may resolve the problem-

Comment: There doesn't seem to a solution atm. Most of the time you can always fall back to simple ajax request instead of using the library.